# I am using javascript sort function on angular scope inside an if condition. My condition is false still it is going inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

Here is the code snippet:

```
$scope.notes = notes.data;
if($scope.notes) {
   console.log("notes", $scope.notes);
} else {
   console.log("no notes");
}

if($scope.notes) {
  console.log("in this if");
  $scope.singleNote = $scope.notes.sort(function(a,b) { 
     return new Date(b.date_posted).getTime() - new Date(a.date_posted).getTime()
  })[0];
}
```

Even if the logic goes in else, it is also going in the 2nd if. It does not display the console of 2nd if but gives an error called: $scope.notes.function is not defined. It should not go in the 2nd if, if it goes in the else block.

Comment: try using a debugger since $scope.notes.function is some other line and not in the second if block.

Comment: how you define function? it should be like $scope.notes = function(){} and need to return something Boolean, true or false.

Comment: @Nikita please provide the whole code around it both HTMl and JS

Comment: @Angular_10 The JS is this much only. And the html is just displaying the singleNote. I am fetching notes from resolver and then assigning it to $scope.notes, notes is an array of objects. Sort function is used to return the note that was last created in $scope.singleNote.

Comment: ok can you tell whats your function name ?

Comment: The problem of course is with your if condition. What is your $scope.notes? The condition `if(value)` will always return true if value is not null or 0 or empty string or NaN or undefined or false.

Comment: @sisyphus The format of my data in $scope.notes was wrong. Used a debugger and resolved it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing occurs because you are declaring to use the array function sort on $scope.notes which is probably not an array at that time the code gets interpreted.
Instead of checking $scope.notes control that $scope.data is defined.

```
$scope.notes = [];
if(notes.data) {
   $scope.notes = notes.data;
   console.log("notes", $scope.notes);
} else {
   console.log("no notes");
}

if($scope.notes.length > 0) {
  console.log("in this if");
  $scope.singleNote = $scope.notes.sort(function(a,b) { 
     return new Date(b.date_posted).getTime() - new Date(a.date_posted).getTime()
  })[0];
}
```